# Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theorem

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Does anyone know of an easy proof of Shannon-McMillan-Brieman theorem?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Igor's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/82278), there's also:

D. Ornstein and B. Weiss, "[The Shannon–McMillan–Breiman theorem for a class of amenable groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02763171)", *Israel J. Math.* **44** (1983), 53–60. [Zbl 0516.28020](https://zbmath.org/0516.28020)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/algoet-sandwich.pdf is pretty nice.